# Could not open error log file on amazon EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've amazon EC2 instance and tried to restart `httpd`, then I got this error

> Starting httpd: (2)No such file or directory: httpd: could not open
>   error log file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log. Unable to open logs

If you have any solution please tell me, I tried many many things

Comment: How you are starting your httpd service ? could you try using sudo keyword before command.

Comment: Try `sudo service httpd restart`